Why does DOMRect shows different values from the chrome's computed values for CSS Absolute position?
I am trying to reposition an absolutely positioned element. If it appears partially or fully beyond the viewpoint then I want to reposition it to appear within the viewpoint. For that, I am trying to get the data using getBoundingClientRect() to know its position and checking the DOMRect bottom value against value of window.innerHeight.
Also, the absolute element's parent is not positioned as relative also nothing in the hierarchy.
If I do,
let pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
if (window.innerHeight < pos['bottom']) {
 style = `botton:${window.innerHeight}`; // set this to the style property of the element.
}

The above does not work and the absolutely positioned element appears in undesired location or does not appear at all. But meanwhile what I have noticed that there are some difference in values that I have got from getBoundingClientRect() and the values displayed in Chrome's  DevTools -> Elements -> Computed.
So for test, if I use values from the Chrome's Computed window and try to set those values in the DevTools: left: 1047.3px - value from the Chrome; it appears exactly where it was positioned originally but when I try left: ${pos['left']}px it displaces the element from its original position.
DOMRect:
  {
    'bottom': 377.68751525878906,
    'height': 159.1354217529297,
    'left': 1075.3333740234375,
    'right': 1231.3333740234375,
    'top': 218.55209350585938,
    'width': 156,
    'x': 1075.3333740234375,
    'y': 218.55209350585938,
  }

Positions from Chrome:

After all, I did not get why those values are different and how to calculate the values to position it within the viewpoint if it goes beyond the bottom edge of the screen.

probably want to use window.clientHeight instead (accounts for borders/bottom scrollbar...) Not sure I have an answer but you might use "fixed" position instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

@browsermator fixed will not work in my case because it always appears at its original position.

"but when I try left: pos['left'] it displaces the element from its original position" - probably because you set an invalid value. A length other than 0 needs a unit.

@CBroe I do add it with a px unit. Mistake in the question

getBoundingClientRect() gets information about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.
So if you have an element with position absolte "inside" another div with position relative
<div #wrapper class="wrapper" style="position:relative">
  <div #inner class="inner" style="position:absolute" [ngStyle]="style">
  </div>
</div>

You use
style:any=null;
@ViewChild('wrapper',{static:true}) wrapper!:ElementRef
@ViewChild('inner',{static:true}) inner!:ElementRef

const rectWrapper = this.inner.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const rect = this.inner.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
this.style = {
  left: rect.left - rectWrapper.left + 'px',
  top: rect.top - rectWrapper.top + 'px',
};

